# SHA2RSA encryption with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, jce

I have been trying to encrypt some data using BouncyCastle's JCE provider. I'm trying "SHA256withRSA" and I'm getting a "noSuchAlgorithmException". Am I doing something wrong? Can someone help? Thanks

Specifically I'm trying

```
Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

As mentioned here - http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt or generate a signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", "BC");
```

In most of the examples I have seen, the second param has a string being passed in vs. the provider itself.

The getInstance method seems to support having a provider passed in, but perhaps just doing

```
 new BouncyCastleProvier()
```

does not construct it properly, resulting in missing algorithms.  I suspect by passing the "BC" string instead, it will use the already constructed provider in JCA/JCE.

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderImplReq

Comment: @praneeth-varma Did you figure it out?

Comment: Firstly, I apologize. I was out of town and didn't check for replies for my question. Please do not mistake. And coming to the problem ...... It worked!. Thanks so much.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a matter of selecting a provider.

I see that the standard SunJSSE Provider supports SHA1withRSA, but not SHA256withRSA.

Somewhere in your code do you have something like this:

```
sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privKey);
```

Comment: I don't. And sorry for my lack of knowledge. I'm not sure of the difference between using a "ContentSigner" built this way and using "Signature" and initializing with private key. Different use cases I suppose?

Comment: The important part I was getting at was the setProvider("BC") part that is telling JCA/JCE to use the BouncyCastle provider.

Comment: Oh okk. Ya I'm doing that. So you think BouncyCastle jce provider does not have SHA256withRSA in the first place?

Comment: No. It does. I wanted to make sure you were using the BouncyCastle provider.

Comment: okk ya I'm specifically telling it to use the provider. I don't know what's going wrong. Thanks much for taking time to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

First add provider

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

And then

```
Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", "BC");
```